# Is there a built in way to get created date and modified date in table row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a built-in way to populate created date and modified date for table rows in SQL Server? I found the following article and it does it by triggers?

http://buildingbettersoftware.blogspot.com/2015/03/populating-created-date-and-last.html

Comment: You could just add default values for those columns if you don't want to manually update them.  Triggers are an ugly way to do anything because they tend to get forgotten.

Comment: But would that work for updates?

Comment: Oh sorry, not for updates.  You would have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not built in for modified, but created can be set via default in a column on the table. SQL Server  2016 introduced temporal tables, but before, you either used triggers or manually inserted into history tables to document the changes.

Since you are running 2014, you need to insert the data into another table to track the modifications. Created by can be tracked in the same manner.